# Patch Diffing office DLLs

Tags: security, assembly, reverse-engineering, patch, binary-diff

I Wonder how two versions of a DLL with only about three months Difference can have over 10KB of size.

These DLLs are related to a Microsoft office product.

[Info of the two DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv7DN.png)

[Size of the two DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IAWr.png)

I am expecting that I am missing something related to patches that Microsoft produces.